# Best way to differentiate between ESTALE and ENOENT in Java

Tags: java, jna, nfs

I'm trying to write a Java application running on a Linux environment on an NFS filesystem.

I noticed that when I call `java.io.File.exists()`, it returns false for both `ESTALE` (Stale NFS file handle) and `ENOENT` (No such file or directory). For my application, I need to be able to differentiate between the two.

Currently I am considering implementing the `stat()` call using JNA, but that seems to be overkill, what with having to implement the whole stat structure and all the `__xstat64` stuff which seems so platform dependent.

Is there a simple way to simply obtain the underlying `errno` after a Java call like `File.exists()` or any other ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JNA, you don't actually have to implement the `stat` structure; you just need to allocate  memory for it sufficiently large to represent the native structure.

You can then call `Native.getLastError()` to retrieve the `errno` value.

```
Pointer fake_stat = new Memory(2048); // big enough
if (clib.stat(filename, fake_stat) != 0) {
    int errno = Native.getLastError();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this suggestion. I also considered implementing `access(file, F_OK)` instead, which was a lot simpler, but turns out also does not differentiate `ESTALE` and `ENOENT`. In the end, however, we found a solution that did not require this differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

If your performance requirements are low, I would just implement a small C program which calls `stat` for a given file name and prints the value of `errno` to stdout. Then call it from Java:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  struct stat buf;
  char const * const fileName = argv[1];
  int const ret = stat(fileName, &buf);
  printf("File %s: Return %d, errno %d\n", fileName, ret, errno);
  if (errno) {
    perror("Error");
  }
}
```

From the command line, this needs 4ms. In your case, possibly you only need to call it, if a previous `exists()` returned false.

Other possibilities: Consider wrapping it in a small TCP server, and let Java communicate with it using sockets. Or use it as a CGI script in apache, and let Java use HTTP.

If this is still too slow, you probably have to go the JNI/JNA way.